# Why does a Yo-Yo spin at all?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, rotation, string

A yo-yo has ball bearings in between the two halves of it. When we drop the yo-yo, the two halves turn too. But if the string is wrapped around the bearing’s ring the shouldn’t it just rotate? Why do the halves rotate?

Comment: http://www.explainthatstuff.com/yoyos.html This article does a good job in explaining most of the physics involved with YOYO.

Comment: yo-yos I have used do not have ball bearings between them. the two halves are connected by a polished steel shaft and all of these parts revolve as a single unit.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/189367/2451 and links therein.